# Quasar (VueX) update state within loop

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

I'm developing a Quasar app and I use VueX to manage my state.

I try to update the properties within my for loop but it doesn't work - when I enter values, they are not getting set in the state.

How can I call the mutations so that they are getting called when the v-model is changed?

```js
<template>
<div class="row q-col-gutter-x-md">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" name="items">

    <h6 class="q-my-sm">Item {{index + 1}}</h6>

    <q-select filled square borderless :v-model="item.prop1" label="Property 1*" :options="options" style="width: 100%;" behavior="menu" class="q-py-md text-subtitle1" />

    <q-input filled square borderless :v-model="item.prop2" label="Property 2*" type="number" min="1" max="9999" style="width: 100%;" />

    <q-input filled square borderless :v-model="item.prop3" label="Property 3*" type="number" min="5" max="90" style="width: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.formInputs.items
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('formInputs/mutationItems', value)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

Comment: `:v-model` is your problem. Colon character (`:`) is a shorthand for `v-bind`, so you are really doing `v-bind:v-model`, which is wrong. Please drop the colons and try again. Unless they're typos... ?

Comment: My god, I feel really bad right now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

As answered by [@Yom S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3634538/yom-s), the error was the colon in front of (:)v-bind, after removing it it works as intended